# With Vuejs, how to use a modal component inside a v-for loop the right way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

In my vue.js app, I need to display a list of items which the user can click.

When clicked, each of these items should then fire a modal, containing additional information about the item that the user just clicked.

What I have so far in my `Items.vue` component is:

```
<template>
    <div id="content">
        <li v-for="item in items" class="list-item pa2 ba">
            <div class="f5 pt2 pb2">
                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Items from '@/api/items';

    export default {
        name: 'items',
        asyncComputed: {
            items: {
                async get() {
                    const items = await Items.getAll();
                    return items.data;
                },
                default: []
            }
        },
        components: {}
    }
</script>
```

Now, I could simply add a modal component to the `v-for` loop, thus creating one modal for each item, but this does not seem ideal if, for example, I have a list of thousands of items.

This led me to believe that the modal should probably be placed at the root of the app (in my case `App.vue`), like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <modal></modal>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app'
    }
</script>
```

and then somehow fired with custom data whenever I needed it.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed. How do I fire this modal with custom information from inside the `v-for` loop, which is in a child component relative to `App.vue`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These two links helped me figure this out:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/passing-data-form-v-for-loop-to-modal-component

#In your Parent Component
You don't have to create a modal for each item within the v-for loop, simply include the modal-component at the beginning of your parent and then work with v-if="..." and props.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <modal v-if="modalVisible" @close="modalVisible = false" :data="modalData"/>

    <div v-for="item in items">
      <button type="button" @click="openModal(item)">Open Modal</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

and then in your script:

```
import modal from './Modal'

export default {
  components: {
    modal
  },
  data() {
    return {
      modalVisible: false,
      modalData: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModal(data) {
      this.modalData = data
      this.modalVisible = true
    },
  }
```

#In your child (modal) component
In your modal you can now do the following:

**Template:**

```
<template>
    {{ data.foo }}
    <button @click="$emit('close')">Cancel</button>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['user']
  };
</script>
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: This was fantastic, I was racking my head on this for a few hours. Simply moving it out of the for loop and passing it data solved my issue of having a modal pop-up for every line item regardless of which on was clicked. +1